# SDL2 rendering text issues

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have a menu where there is a lot of text being rendered that can change in size/color/position, so I made two functions in my menu class...:

```
void drawText(string text,int text_size,int x,int y, Uint8 r,Uint8 g,Uint8 b);
void updateTexts();
```

The updateTexts() function sits in the game loop and contains many drawText functions, When I launch the program I notice the programs memory gradually increase from 4mb about 1gb (it should stay at 4mb) then it crashes. I assume the problem exists because TTF_OpenFont" is run constantly though I needed a way to be able to create new font sizes on the fly as my menu changes based on the users input.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

code for the two functions:

```
void Menu::drawText(string text,int text_size,int x,int y, Uint8 r,Uint8 g,Uint8 b)
{
    TTF_Font* arial = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf",text_size);
    if(arial == NULL)
    {
        printf("TTF_OpenFont: %s\n",TTF_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Color textColor = {r,g,b};
    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(arial,text.c_str(),textColor);
    if(surfaceMessage == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to render text surface: %s\n",TTF_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Texture* message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,surfaceMessage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);
    int text_width = surfaceMessage->w;
    int text_height = surfaceMessage->h;
    SDL_Rect textRect{x,y,text_width,text_height};

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,message,NULL,&textRect);
}

void Menu::updateTexts()
{
    drawText("Item menu selection",50,330,16,0,0,0);
    drawText("click a menu item:",15,232,82,0,0,0);
    drawText("item one",15,59,123,0,0,0);
    drawText("item two",15,249,123,0,0,0);
    drawText("item three",15,439,123,0,0,0);
    drawText("item four",15,629,123,0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each opened font, created surface and created texture uses memory.

If collection of different resources that you require is limited, e.g. only 3 different `text_size`, it's better to create them once and then reuse.
For example by storing them in some kind of cache:

```
std::map<int, TTF_Font*> fonts_cache_;

TTF_Font * Menu::get_font(int text_size) const
{
  if (fonts_cache_.find(text_size) != fonts_cache_.end())
  {
    // Font not yet opened. Open and store it.
    fonts_cache_[text_size] = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf",text_size);
    // TODO: error checking...
  }

  return fonts_cache_[text_size];
}

void Menu::drawText(string text,int text_size,int x,int y, Uint8 r,Uint8 g,Uint8 b)
{
  TTF_Font* arial = get_font(text_size)
  ...
}

Menu::~Menu()
{
  // Release memory used by fonts
  for (auto pair : fonts_cache_)
    TTF_CloseFont(pair.second);
  ...
}
```

For dynamic resources that should be allocated on each method invocation you should not forget to free them. Currently you are not releasing memory of `TTF_Font* arial`, `SDL_Texture* message`; do:

```
void Menu::drawText(string text,int text_size,int x,int y, Uint8 r,Uint8 g,Uint8 b)
{
  ...
  TTF_CloseFont(arial);
  SDL_DestroyTexture(message);
}
```

Comment: Did what you said and fixed the problem. thanks a lot.

 I didn't even know that you could close a font :) :)

Comment: Creating and destroying surfaces every time you need to change text gives poor performance. As such I made a system where the font is loaded once and i make a single texture using a character map. Then use the map to 'look up' characters to render when displaying a string. Similar to how you would do a bitmap font